# Trouble trying to join two tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, netezza, partition

This is my first post on this forum so apologies if I am unclear or my question is not formatted correctly.

I have the following table, TABLE_MONTHS:

```
|   Date    | Year_Part | Month_part |
 31-01-2016     2016           1
 29-02-2016     2016           2
 31-03-2016     2016           3
 30-04-2016     2016           4
    ...         ...           ...
```

This table simply goes through the whole year of 2016, where the first column is the last day of each month.

I also have another table, TABLE_SAVINGS:

```
|   Date    | Year_Part | Month_part | Cumulative_Saved |
 03-01-2016     2016           1              50
 07-03-2016     2016           3             150
 25-03-2016     2016           3             275 
 14-07-2016     2016           7             400
    ...         ...           ...
```

This table shows each date I have put some money into my savings bank account and the amount put away.

What I am after is a join these two tables, such that the resulting table looks like this:

```
|   Date    | Year_Part | Month_part | Cumulative_Saved |
 31-01-2016     2016           1              50
 29-02-2016     2016           2              50
 31-03-2016     2016           3             275 
 30-04-2016     2016           4             275
 31-05-2016     2016           5             275
 30-06-2016     2016           6             275
 31-07-2016     2016           7             400
    ...         ...           ...
```

Essentially a table which, instead of just having the exact dates of when I deposited money into my savings account, gives me a month-by-month recording of how much is in my savings account.

My problem is that I am struggling to figure out the logic for the join of these two tables for the result I would like.

After many attempts at trying to get this to work, the 'best' I have managed to come up with is,

```
SELECT
    A.*,
    MAX(B.Cumulative_Saved) OVER
        (PARTITION BY B.Month_part ORDER BY B.Month_part ASC)
FROM
    TABLE_MONTHS A
LEFT JOIN
    TABLE_SAVINGS B
    ON A.[Date] <= B.[Date]
```

But this will also join the earlier dates from TABLE_MONTHS onto the later dates from TABLE_SAVINGS so I end up with multiple dates multiple rows for each date from TABLE_MONTHS.

I also realise that this will only work properly if the Cumulative_Saved field only ever increases (which, in my data, it does not) as I would otherwise not necessarily pick the row which has the data closest to the end of month date from my first table.

I really am struggling with these and would appreciate an answer, I really can't see any way to get this to work.

Please let me know if any of this is unclear and I will try to clarify what I mean.

I have access to Netezza and SSMS so an answer for either would be best.

Thank you in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easier in SQL Server, using a lateral join:

```
select tm.*, ts.Cumulative_Saved
from table_months tm outer apply
     (select top 1 tm
      from table_saving ts
      where ts.date <= tm.date
      order by ds.date desc
     ) ts;
```

You can do this in Netezza using `lag()` with `ignore nulls`:

```
select tm.*,
       coalesce(ts.Cumulative_Saved,
                lag(ts.Cumulative_Saved ignore nulls) over (order by tm.date)
               ) as Cumulative_Saved
from table_months tm left join
     (select ts.*,
             row_number() over (partition by date_trunc('month', ts.date) order by ts.date desc) as seqnum
      from table_saving ts
     ) ts
     on date_trunc('month', ts.date) = date_trunc('month', tm.date) and
        seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL is not the best solution for such requirements. In my opinion a subselect ( SELECT TOP 1 Cumulative_Saved WHERE... ORDER BY...) should do the trick and be much more readable than a complex join.